# Classification of artifacts in Gradle 5?

Tags: android, gradle

Problem:
Publish javadoc and sources for a gradle project. The following code works well, even on Gradle 5.1.1:

```
task sourcesJar(type: Jar) {
    from android.sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs
    classifier = 'sources'
}

task javadoc(type: Javadoc) {
    source = android.sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs
    classpath += project.files(android.getBootClasspath().join(File.pathSeparator))
}

task javadocJar(type: Jar, dependsOn: javadoc) {
    classifier = 'javadoc'
    from javadoc.destinationDir
}

artifacts {
    archives javadocJar
    archives sourcesJar
}
```

However, in Gradle 5.1.1 the following statements are deprecated:

```
classifier = 'sources'

...

classifier = 'javadoc'
```

Looking at the javadoc for the evaluated method name reveals:

> Deprecated.
>   Use getArchiveClassifier()
>
> Source: https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/tasks/bundling/AbstractArchiveTask.html#setClassifier-java.lang.String-

This doesn't make sense to me.

**What change is required for my code to continue to work and not be deprecated?**

Comment: I asked the same question on the gradle forum a while ago: https://discuss.gradle.org/t/how-does-property-class-work-in-build-configuration/30320 You can really just use archiveClassifier = 'sources' instead. I guess it's some gradle magic involving special handling of properties.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Following will not show deprecation warning:

```
    archiveClassifier.set("sources")

    archiveClassifier.set("javadoc")
```

Comment: IntelliJ IDEA inspection produces warning: 'set' in 'org.gradle.api.provider.Property<T>' cannot be applied to '(java.lang.String)' ... although it still works okay